# Adding an icon to a button with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

My problem is very simple but I could not find even a simple sample code. Can anyone kindly tell me how to add an image on a button? Here is my sample jQuery button:

```
$("<input>", {
    type: "button",
    name: "deletebutton_" + li_name + "_" + li_index,
    id: "deletebutton_" + li_name + "_" + li_index,
    click: function() {
        //do something
    },
}).appendTo(dv);
```

Comment: Also note that trailing `,` comma behind the click event handler will cause problems with IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a `button` instead of an `input` element with type set to `button`, since only `button` can contain other HTML elements. Something like this should work:

```
var btn = $('<button />', {
    // Various properties
});

$('<img />', {
    alt: '', 
    src: 'path/to/img.png'
}).prependTo(btn);
```

Alternatively, you might wish to consider using something like [jQuery UI's button component](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button).

---

Another alternative is to use CSS to add in icon:

```
input.icon {
    background: url('path/to/imag.png') no-repeat;
    padding-left: 12px;
}
```

The padding is there to give the icon some space.

**See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/dvjVV/ a live demo of how both of these methods work.**

Comment: Thanks mate. You have just saved my life.. I was about driving nuts. can you suggest me a book of jquery basics ? I am sick of spending hours for searching simple things.

Comment: @user I think you should try getting started with HTML and CSS first - this is, after  all, technically speaking a HTML problem - try the Web Standards Curriculum for starters: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/

Comment: Thanks. You are right I am not good at html. However, even if I have knowledge about it, I cannot think of .prependTo(btn); solution. Anyway, I am trying to get used to it. Thanks again.